# Xamarin Forms: Calling DAL method to different page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I create an event on one page that is stored into the database and I would like to call that into my listview on a separate page. I know how to do this on the same page as the event was created but I would like it to be on a separate page of events.

```
private async void ScheduleEventBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //AddEventFields fields = new AddEventFields(Entry_Host.Text, Entry_Name.Text, Entry_Address.Text);

            // dont think i need this anymore
            if (!fields.CheckFields())
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Empty Fields", "Please Make sure all Fields are filled out", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                Events events = new Events();
                events.HostName = Entry_Host.Text;
                events.EventsName = Entry_Name.Text;
                events.EventAddress = Entry_Address.Text;
                events.NumberOfPeople = Entry_People.Text;
                events.DateOfEvent = DatePicker.Date;
                events.TimeOfEvent = TimePicker.Time;

                DAL dal = new DAL();
                dal.AddEvent(events);

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyEvents());
            }
            
        }
```

page I want to call it too but cannot find the exact route to be able to configure this.

```
public MyEvents()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        lvEvent.ItemsSource = dal.GetAllItems();
    }
```

Comment: do you just want to know how to access your DAL from the 2nd page?

Comment: Whoever posted helped me fix my issue, their comment is deleted but all i had to do was pass my newly created DAL. Also is there any friendly documentation with these kind of examples, microsoft docs doesnt always have the easiest to understand documentation

Comment: @trucetht Hi, have you solved this ? If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first page, pass the new `Event` to the 2nd page

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyEvents(events));
```

then modify the constructor of the 2nd page

```
public MyEvents(Events events)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // do something with events here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ive decided not to pass that, I was wodering how I would call the GetAllEvents method in my DAL.cs file from my my events page

Comment: I originally deleted this because I wasn't sure it was what you were asking for, so I asked for clarification, and you told me that it was exactly what you needed.  Now you're saying it isn't.  Very confusing.  That said, if you want to call some DAL method, just create in instance of your DAL and call it.  Just like you do in your other page.

Comment: Thank you, it did help with what I was asking, but i kept getting an object reference error. So I was wanting to take a different route